# What is the best way to append to an array in each iteration of a loop on a map using clojure?

Tags: string, loops, clojure

I have created a structure which builds a URL query from a map but it is not thread-safe since it's relying on a defined variable which probably isn't needed so what is the best way to do this?

```
(def charset "UTF-8")
(defn make-query
    [params]    
    (do
      (def tmpa [])
      (doseq [keyval params] 
         (def tmpa 
             (into tmpa 
                 [(str 
                    (java.net.URLEncoder/encode (name (first keyval)) charset) 
                    "=" 
                    (java.net.URLEncoder/encode (apply (first keyval) [params]) charset)
                 )]
             )
         )
      )
      (clojure.string/join "&" tmpa)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of nested `def`s is not really the way to go when you need to work with an intermediate value in a function, that's what the `let` form is for. Also note that `def` creates a top level var, so even after the `make-query` function returns, you will still have a `tmpa` var lying around in the namespace where you declared the function.

The function you posted has an imperative style since it's using `doseq` (which is [by definition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) to be used for side-effects) and changing the value of the `tmpa` var in every iteration of the loop.

A functional approach would be `reduce`ing the key-value pairs and build the result by concatenating the key and value to the query string in each call to the reducing function. The following is an example of how this can be achieved:

```
(def charset "UTF-8")
(defn make-query
    [params]    
    (reduce (fn [query [k v]]
              (str query
                   (java.net.URLEncoder/encode (name k) charset)
                   "="
                   (java.net.URLEncoder/encode (str v) charset)
                   "&"))
            ""
            params))

(make-query {:name "clojure" :year 2014})
;= "name=clojure&year=2014&"
```

It takes some time to get used to thinking this way, when one comes from an imperative and OOP background, but with practice it gets a lot easier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the def was public and that it was nothing but trouble but it was the only thing that worked. I'll need to play with this method a bit because the join is important as there shouldn't be a trailing & on a query.

Comment: Ok, solved it with a variation of your solution. (defn make-query [params]
     (let [arr (reduce (fn [query [k v]] (into query [(str (java.net.URLEncoder/encode (name k) "UTF-8") "=" (java.net.URLEncoder/encode (str v) "UTF-8"))])) [] params
         )]
      (clojure.string/join "&" arr)
   ))